# How to draw a zigzag line?

Tags: winforms, system.drawing

I am creating a document based application and i want to draw a horizontal line underlying the text. But, line should not be straight. i want to draw a line like this.
[image: Zigzag line]

Currently i am using `System.Graphics` object to draw any object.

```
private void DrawLine(Graphics g, Point Location, int iWidth)
{
    iWidth = Convert.ToInt16(iWidth / 2);
    iWidth = iWidth * 2;
    Point[] pArray = new Point[Convert.ToInt16(iWidth / 2)];
    int iNag = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < iWidth; i+=2)
    {
        pArray[(i / 2)] = new Point(Location.X + i , Location.Y + iNag);
        if (iNag == 0)
            iNag = 2;
        else
            iNag = 0;
    }
    g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, pArray);
}
```

**UPDATED**:
Above code is working fine and line draws perfectly but, this code effects on application performance. Is there another way to do this thing.

Comment: Is the above code not working or are you just looking for a better solution?

Comment: Sorry i have forgot to add this specification. so i have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fast drawing just make a png image of the line you want, with width larger than you need and then draw the image:

```
private void DrawLine(Graphics g, Point Location, int iWidth)
{
    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, iWidth, zigzagLine.Height);
    Rectangle dstRect = new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, iWidth, zigzagLine.Height);

    g.DrawImage(zigzagLine, dstRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

zigzagLine is the bitmap.

valter

Comment: Thanks for your answer valter. But, the line will be stretched or shrieked with the different width of line. what happen if image size is 50px and there are two lines of 10px and 90px?

Comment: @Nimesh That's why I said *with width larger than you need*. What I meant was, find the max width that your program will ever use and then make a bitmap this width plus 1.